# Java array init block with null

Tags: java

Can somebody tell me how to interpret the following code?  I know how to use blocks to initialize multi-dimensional arrays, but exactly what the null does in this example has me stumped.  What will the contents of the whole array be?  Thanks.

```
int arry[][] = { {1, 2}, null };`
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is same, In Java, array is also another object, so assign null is perfectly OK

```
arry[0] = {1, 2};
arry[1] = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have multi-dimensional arrays. It only has arrays of arrays.

```
arry is an array of 2 int[]s
    arry[0] is an array of 2 ints
        (arry[0])[0] is 1
        (arry[0])[1] is 2
    arry[1] is null
```